# Ошибка сборки проекта в visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

При попытке запустить только что созданный проект в Visual Studio, с уже заранее имеющимя там кодом(C#), программа говорит о том что не удалось собрать проект. Подробно ошибку видно на фото [image: Сам код и ошибка]

Comment: Проверьте файл .csproj. Может там указана ссылка на этот файл?

Comment: Нашёл ещё вот статейку - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440223/assets-file-project-assets-json-not-found-run-a-nuget-package-restore и вот видео, если не поймёте https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnlvZqawjtY

Comment: Текст ошибки надо текстом вставлять, а то я хотел погуглить, но перепечатывать с картинки не буду.